# multi-part upload Google Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to implement multi-part upload to Google Storage but to my surprise it does not seem to be straightforward (I could not find java example).

Only mention I found was in the XML API https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/multipart-uploads

Also found some discussion around a compose API [StorageExample.java#L446](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/c3d18ffce9d9895550dd5d2acc1d0ff125305898/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/storage/StorageExample.java#L446) mentioned here [google-cloud-java issues 1440](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/1440)

Any recommendations how to do multipart upload?

Comment: I get the impression that the multi-part upload API for Google Storage may be related to AWS S3 compatibility libraries.  See this article ... https://vamsiramakrishnan.medium.com/a-study-on-using-google-cloud-storage-with-the-s3-compatibility-api-324d31b8dfeb

If this holds water, then the samples you may be looking for may be the AWS samples for the equivalent function with GCS saying "Me too".

Comment: The Java SDK supports **Parallel composite uploads**. See this link: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/resumable-uploads#behavior

Comment: @Kolban I think the S3 solution works for me cause my app already does uploads to S3 and now I'm looking on how to do the same for GS. I will give it a try, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the multi-part upload working with @Koblan suggestion. (for details check [blog post](https://dzlab.github.io/gcp/2022/02/26/gs-with-s3-sdk/))

This is how I create the S3 Client and point it to Google Storage

```java
def createClient(accessKey: String, secretKey: String, region: String = "us"): AmazonS3 = {
    val endpointConfig = new EndpointConfiguration("https://storage.googleapis.com", region)
    val credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)
    val credentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)
    val clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration()
    clientConfig.setUseGzip(true)
    clientConfig.setMaxConnections(200)
    clientConfig.setMaxErrorRetry(1)
    val clientBuilder = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
    clientBuilder.setEndpointConfiguration(endpointConfig)
    clientBuilder.withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
    clientBuilder.withClientConfiguration(clientConfig)
    clientBuilder.build()
  }
```

Because I'm doing the upload from the frontend (after I generate signled URLs for each part using the AmazonS3 client) I needed to enable CORS.

For testing, I enabled everything for now

```
$ gsutil cors get gs://bucket
$ echo '[{"origin": ["*"],"responseHeader": ["Content-Type", "ETag"],"method": ["GET", "HEAD", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"],"maxAgeSeconds": 3600}]' > cors-config.json
$ gsutil cors set cors-config.json gs://bucket
```

See https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors#gsutil_1

Answer (score 1):

Currently Java Client library for multi part upload in Cloud Storage is not available.  You can raise a feature request for the same in this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187243&template=1162869). As mentioned by John Hanley, the next best thing you can do is, do a [parallel composite upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploads-downloads#parallel-composite-uploads) with gsutil (CLI), JSON and XML support/ [resumable upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/resumable-uploads#java) with Java libraries.

In parallel compose, the parallel writes can be done by using the JSON or XML API for Google Cloud Storage. Specifically, you would write a number of smaller objects in parallel and then (once all of those objects have been written) call the Compose request to compose them into one larger object.

If you're using the JSON API the compose documentation is at : https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/compose

If you're using the XML API the compose documentation is at : https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference-methods#putobject (see the compose query parameter).

Also there is an interesting document link provided by Kolban which you can try and work out. Also I would like to mention that you can have multi part uploads in Java, if you use the Google Drive API(v3). Here is the [code example](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#java) where  we use the [files.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) method with uploadType=multipart.

Comment: my use case is that I need to generate pre-signed URLs for multi-part upload in the backend and then lot the client-side chunk a file and upload each chunk with one of the URLs. si the drive API does not work, I will check how to use the composite API.